# How to add C Flags in Android Studio using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to add C Flags in my Android Studio project.

Here's what I did:

```
android {
        // openFrameworks currently only supports compiling against SDK 19
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cFlags "-DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DUSEAPI_DUMMY -DPD -DLIBPD_EXTRA -DLIBPD_USE_STD_MUTEX"
                }
            }
        }
```

But I get:

> Gradle DSL method not found: 'cFlags()'

How can I properly add C Flags in gradle?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Which gradle plugin version are you using?

Comment: @Michael I used 3.3 version.